# WPF Designer Failing to Load Generic.xaml

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, designer

I have written a WPF Class Library. It has a Generic.xaml file under a themes folder in the project and also a ThemeInfo attribute in the AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, 
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly)]
```

All works well, except in the designer. I get blue squigly lines anywhere I am using StaticResource to reference my brushes, styles and other resources saying:

> The resource '[Resource Name]' cannot be found.

I really want the designer to pick up my Generic.xaml file and show the controls **as I have styled them**. How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**

I have marked Yogesh's answer as correct but here is some more information. I was adding the resource dictionary in the constructor of the App.xaml file, instead of in the xaml. The XAML designer does not seem to execute the code behind for the App.xaml file.

Comment: If you want to use `Generic.xaml`, then use a `CustomControl` library. Class libraries have no such file like `App.xaml`.

Comment: It is not a WPF Application project which has an App.xaml. I am using a WPF UserControl Library (Which is just a Class Library with the ThemeInfo attribute) with a Generic.xaml file under a Themes folder. I then reference this Generic.xaml file from App.xaml in another WPF Application project.

Comment: @RehanSaeed can you provide a minimum package which is causing the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a new page named `App.xaml` with `Application` as the root element in the class library with `Build Action` set to `Page`. Now add the generic.xaml file as a resource dictionary. Something like this...

```
<Application x:Class="[YourNamespace].App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="[AbsoluteOrRelativePath]/Generic.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

After you do this, rebuild your project, close all xaml views and reopen them again. This should fix your issue in VS2012/2013 and Blend 2012.

Comment: I have this already. As I say, my xaml works fine at runtime. Just fails in the designer.

Comment: @RehanSaeed So why do you accept this as an answer if it does not help you?

Comment: Because that is the correct method of adding resource dictionaries.